# Watchdog for Linux

Tags: linux

Are there any watchdog tools or libraries on Linux for the following purpose? I would like to build a watchdog executable which starts 2 processes and restarts them if:

- processes crash
- processes become unresponsive (e.g. hang for some reason)

Internet search found `watchdog.c` but I am not sure if that can be used for my purposes, it looks pretty low level.

I could run my processes as init programs (daemons) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072879/how-to-use-linux-software-watchdog), but I am not sure if Linux would then recognize that the process is hanging (e.g. due to a deadlock)

Answer (score 2):

We use monit here: http://mmonit.com/monit/ it will let you do the restart thing it is also highly customizable regarding how to check and how to react via scripts